# initialising and accessing an array of weights in a custom keras layer

Tags: keras

I am writing a custom keras layer for convolution in a cnn architecture in fourier domain:

```python
class Fourier_Conv2D(Layer):
def __init__(self, no_of_kernels, **kwargs):
    self.no_of_kernels = no_of_kernels
    super(Fourier_Conv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel', 
                                  shape = input_shape + (self.no_of_kernels,), 
                                  initializer = 'uniform', trainable = True)
    super(Fourier_Conv2D, self).build(input_shape)

def call(self, x):
    return K.dot(x, self.kernel[0])
```

In the call function, I need to do pointwise multiplication of the fft of input with fft of each kernel (according to the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)) and add the products before passing this sum to activation function. But how can I access each weight separately in the call function, as using array index to do so is giving the following attribute error -

```python
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-9617a8e7ab2e> in <module>()
      1 x = Fourier_Conv2D(5)
----> 2 x.call((2,2,1))

<ipython-input-70-02ded53b8f6f> in call(self, x)
     11 
     12     def call(self, x):
---> 13         return K.dot(x, self.kernel[0])
     14 

AttributeError: 'Fourier_Conv2D' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

Thanks in advance for any help in solving the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using your layer correctly. The line `x.call((2,2,1))` makes no sense since you need to pass a tensor to the layer. You should instead do something like this:

```
x = Input((3,4))
custom_layer = Fourier_Conv2D(10)
output = custom_layer(x)
```

Moreover, there are some errors in the definition of your layer. The following should work:

```
class Fourier_Conv2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, no_of_kernels, **kwargs):
        self.no_of_kernels = no_of_kernels
        super(Fourier_Conv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Note the changes to the shape parameter
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel', 
                                      shape = (int(input_shape[-1]), self.no_of_kernels), 
                                      initializer = 'uniform', trainable = True)
        super(Fourier_Conv2D, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        return K.dot(x, self.kernel) # kernel[0] --> kernel
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt help, this indeed removes the error.

Comment: But I have a doubt about the shape of the weights. Suppose I have an image of shape (height=28, weight=28,no_of_channels=1), and no_of_kernels=5, then the shape of the kernel according to your formula would be (1,5).. but we need 5 kernels each of shape (28,28,1) i.e. collective shape of the kernels = (28,28,5)
Another ques. is now if we do add a weight of shape (28,28,5), then we need total 5 ptwise multiplications (between the image and the 5 kernels). So would we not need to loop over index kernel[0..4] to do these mults?

Comment: My code only works for 2D input. It was not clear from your question that you wanted to apply it to 3D input. Also note that the method `K.dot` does matrix multiplication, not a dot product as is normally used in convolutional layers. If you simply want to take the dot products with 5 kernels then why not use the Conv2D layer from Keras? Conv2D(5, kernel_size=(28,28))

Comment: No here by dot product I mean dot product between fft of weight padded to image size and fft of image, which is the fourier domain equivalent of convolution according to the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). So I want to replace the conv2d layer of keras by a custom pointwise multiplication layer of fourier transforms of image and kernel.

Comment: So you mean the pointwise product of input and kernel instead of dot product? (dot product returns a single number, pointwise product the same shape as input.) In that case you should not use `K.dot` but instead simply multiply input and kernel: `input * kernel`. And make sure your kernel has shape `(28, 28, 1, n_kernels)` or `(28, 28, n_kernels)`, no need to use a for loop as the input will automatically be broadcast to a compatible shape.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I'm sorry I am a beginner in Keras so could you please tell what will be the expression for the shape of the weight as (height, width, no_of_kernels), like for e.g., (28,28,5) given the input_shape=(28,28,1) and no_of_kernels=5 ?

Comment: You can for example do like this: `kernel_shape = [int(input_shape[1]), int(input_shape[2]), self.no_of_kernels]`